# should ::std::remove_cv<> work on function types?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to extract the return and argument types of a member function without having to bother with `const` and `volatile` overloads, but it seems to me, that `::std::remove_cv<>` does not work with function types:

```
template <typename>
struct signature
{
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct signature<R(A...)>
{
};

template <typename C, typename F>
constexpr auto extract_function_type(F C::* const) noexcept
{
  return signature<::std::remove_cv_t<F>>();
}

template <typename F>
constexpr auto extract_signature(F const&) noexcept ->
  decltype(&F::operator(), extract_function_type(&F::operator()))
{
  return extract_function_type(&F::operator());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `const` function type:

[dcl.fct]/6:

> The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top
>   of the function type. In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored. [Note: a function type that has a
>   cv-qualifier-seq is not a cv-qualified type; there are no cv-qualified function types. —end note]

You will have to write your own type trait:

```
template<typename T>
struct remove_cv_seq;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct remove_cv_seq<R (Args...) const> {
    using type = R (Args...);
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct remove_cv_seq<R (Args...)> {
    using type = R (Args...);
};

struct Foo {
    remove_cv_seq<void () const>::type bar;
};

int main()
{
    Foo const x;
    x.bar(); // This will fail to compile because it tries to call non-const member function.
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I figured so much, how about ref-qualified function types, do I need to strip those too?

Comment: @user1095108 yeah. There is a lot of boilerplate. I posted the bare minimum.

Comment: Ok, ok, if there exists a more elegant solution without the boilerplate, please add to your answer.